# Как выделить активный пункт меню?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Делаю сайт без движка. Изначально было 5 HTML-страниц. И в каждой странице к соответствующему пункту меню задавался класс .current. Но теперь количество страниц увеличилось до 20-30. И я решил создать файл header.php и в каждой странице вызвать этот хедер. И получается теперь что во всех 20-30 страницах активным остается только 1 пункт меню, которому задан класс .current. Можно ли сделать, что бы этот класс задавался автоматически к активному пункту меню? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В PHP есть глобальная переменная $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], в котором URI страницы. Можно воспользоваться этим и подключить класс к меню. Рекомендую добавить в массив все пункты меню и отрисовывать через **foreach** при этом проверяя меню на активность.

```
$menu = array(
    array('url'=>'/main.php','title'=>'Главное'),
    array('url'=>'/about.php','title'=>'О сайте'),
    array('url'=>'/articles.php','title'=>'Статьи'),    
);
foreach($menu as $item)
{
    $output .= "<a href='{$item['url']}' {($item['url']==$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?'class=\'active\''}>{$item['title']}</a>";
}
```

Если хотите сделать через JavaScript, то придётся посложнее, надо будет поискать пункты меню, среди них выбрать того, чей **document.location.pathname** совпадает с **elem.href**, где **elem** пункт меню. И добавить присвоить класс к этому элементу через **elem.className += " active"**

Если используете `jQuery` в своём проекте то будет чуть попроще

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('menu a').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href')==document.location.pathname) $(this).addClass('active')
    }
 })
```

P.S.: Покажите код